# How to put an Item in aws DynamoDb using aws Lambda with JAVA

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have created **AWS Java Lambda project** from **ECLIPSE IDE**. In the **handle request** section I want to process the request and insert it into a **AWS DynamoDB** table. In

I can see this can be easily done using **node.js**. Lot of code samples are available. Is there a proper **JAVA** help available. I am new to JAVA and struggling to find this. Any help is appreciated.

```
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;
public class LambdaHandler implements RequestHandler<Object, Object> {
    @Override
    public Object handleRequest(Object input, Context context) {
        context.getLogger().log("Input: " + input);
        // TODO: implement DYNAMO DB INSERT
        return input;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the api in package com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2 (maven dependency artifactID= aws-java-sdk-dynamodb )

```
AWSCredentials creds = new BasicAWSCredentials("myacceskey","mysecretkey");
AmazonDynamoDBClient dyndbclient = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(creds);
String tableName = "myDynamoDbTable"
Map<String, AttributeValue> dbItem = new HashMap<String, AttributeValue>();
//TODO put key/values from request in dbItem
dyndbclient.putItem(tableName, dbItem);
```

You may also want to redefine your lambda handler function, so that you have a better cast input parameter than your current (Object input )

Comment: Assuming he is using dynamodb in the same account as in lambda function, he can ignore the credentials while creating AmazonDynamoDBClient object. `AmazonDynamoDBClient dynamoDBClient = new AmazonDynamoDBClient();` Just providing enough permissions for operations on DynamoDB in Lambda function role will suffice.

Comment: As I said I am new to JAVA. I configured the project using ECLIPSE IDE.The "import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2 cannot be resolved" is the error ECLIPSE is showing when I tried to include this.

Comment: Try adding the following maven dependency to pom.xml (in the root of your project) : <dependency>
   <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
   <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
   <version>LATEST</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: Not able to find any pom.xml file in my root directory. Everything works fine when I create JAVA Project. Issue starts when I create JAVA LAMDA Projecr

Comment: you can download the jar file dependency here ( http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb/1.10.30/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.10.30.jar) Than, add it to your eclipse project: https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_add_an_extra_library_to_my_project's_classpath%3F

Comment: At version 1.1.0 the proper way to get the client is through AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.defaultClient()